# parsing CSV file to castom objects, which has one of fields like ENUM

Tags: java, opencsv

The question is, how I should handle ENUM fields for right parsing. Maybe it has another sort of annotation or something... I get symbol from csv file and have to create the enum in right type. But how can I do that?...

This implementation throw too long message. The first string is:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: com.opencsv.exceptions.CsvBeanIntrospectionException: Basic instantiation of the given bean type (and subordinate beans created through recursion, if applicable) was determined to be impossible.

It throws it in a string with [.parse();]

public class FileServiceImplementation implements FileService {

```
public List<FruitTransaction> read(File file) {
        try (FileReader reader = new FileReader(file)) {
            return new CsvToBeanBuilder(reader)
                    .withType(FruitTransaction.class)
                    .build()
                    .parse();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Cannot read file: " + file.getName() + e);
        }
    }
}

public class FruitTransaction {
    @CsvBindByPosition(position = 0)
    private Operation operation;
    @CsvBindByPosition(position = 1)
    private String fruit;
    @CsvBindByPosition(position = 2)
    private int quantity;

...
// and my nested enum class:
public enum Operation {
        BALANCE("b"),
        SUPPLY("s"),
        PURCHASE("p"),
        RETURN("r");

        private String operation;

        Operation(String operation) {
            this.operation = operation;
        }
    }
}

my input data from CSV file:
b,banana,20
b,apple,100
s,banana,100
p,banana,13
r,apple,10
p,apple,20
p,banana,5
s,banana,50
```

Comment: Your question implies a problem. Do you get an error or what?

Comment: yes. Sorry, forgot to add exception message.

Comment: Bad news - you've got a worse problem: your file enum value doesn't reflect the variable name of the enum value and I don't think the enum ctor helps. Good news - this fascinated me and I have a full working solution for you :)